# plone zodb ERROR CMFUid ASSERT

Tags: plone, zodb

we have a very large Data.fs (~15Gb) - I think this comes trough usage of "Working Copy Support" with custom folderish content types!

If I try to use "portal_historiestorage", the instance quits and shows > XX errors of:

```
ERROR CMFUid ASSERT: 17 objects have 1642 as uid!!!
```

How can I clear this objects and shrink my DB?
I already cleared/rebuild "portal_catalog", reference_catalog and uid_catalog

thanks in advance

plone 3.3.6

Comment: Have you ever [packed your zodb](http://plone.org/documentation/faq/how-do-i-pack-the-zodb)?

Comment: Does the instance process segfault? Which operating system you are running (which bitness)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this kind of problem.
In my case it was the cmf_uid index missing in the portal_catalog: so every search was returning all the catalog brains.

So I guess that the problem in the question was related to the fact that multiple objects have been indexed with the same cmf_uid (which is an attribute on the object).

```
[b.getObject() for b in portal_catalog(cmf_uid='1642')]
```

should point out the relevant objects.

You should take the objects and verify they have a proper cmf_uid, taking care of possible acquisition problems.